# Reflection. Why does my line return null in the code, but works fine in the debugger?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a line of code, an assignment, that assigns null when run, but when I visit in the debugger, the line does just what I want. The line is...

```
object instance = typeof(SqlEditorPackage).GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null);
```

In the below screenshot, you can see the local variable `instance` is null, whereas in the watch, the same line gives me a populated object. What is going on?

[image]

If this gives anyone ideas, here is the code for the Instance prop, from the SqlEditorPackage.dll, visited with ilspy

```
    internal static SqlEditorPackage Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = (DemandLoadPackage("fef13793-c947-4fb1-b864-c9f0be9d9cf6") as SqlEditorPackage);
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        private set
        {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }
```

Enabling all exceptions, I see the following error, one of about 15 of the same type for various assemblies...

Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' 
  Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' : 'The assembly named 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor' was loaded from 'file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/SQLEditor/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.dll' using the LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in unexpected behavior for serialization, casting and dependency resolution. In almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom context be avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.'

I don't know if this is part of the problem, but I note that this refers to a 2019 version of SqlEditorPackage, not the 2015 version that I have referenced.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the property in the object's thread? See its Dispatcher thread and compare it with your current thread.

Comment: It does not seem to be reflection issue, TBH.

Comment: @TimeS I added ThrowIfNotOnUIThread() at the top of my method. No improvement. I also tried putting in a loop to repeat it 10 times, and a number of other desperate permutations. No juice. Works every time in the debugger. Works never in my code.

Comment: A debugger can change many things. So unless you share a complete sample somewhere for others to review, this question is impossible to answer.